# Check my solution for the continuity of this function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, continuity

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^4y^3}{x^8 + y^4} & (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \\\\ 0 & (x, y) = (0, 0)\end{cases}$$

After having tried a couple of paths, getting $0$ as a limit, I took it as a good starting point, and thence I tried to prove the function is indeed continuous at the origin:

$$\bigg|\frac{x^4y^3}{x^8 + y^4} - 0 \bigg| = \frac{x^4y^2|y|}{x^8+y^4}$$

Now by AM/GM: $x^8 + y^4 \geq 2\sqrt{x^8y^4} = 2x^4y^2$ hence

$$\frac{x^4y^2|y|}{x^8+y^4} \leq \frac{x^4y^2|y|}{2x^4y^2} = \frac{1}{2}|y| \leq \frac{1}{2}(|y| + |x|) \leq C\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \to 0$$

When $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$.

For some constant $C$ we do not care about (it's finite and positive). That shall be the norm in $\ell^2$: I studied that I can always perform this:
$$|x| + |y| \leq C \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

So, did I well?

Comment: Well, I used legit inequalities, like AM/GM and the norm in $\ell^2$. I'm just a bit insecure of myself, but I would like to think I did right :D

Comment: The formalism “(x,y)→(0,0)” means “approaching the origin in an indeterminate fashion”. Therefore if there is at least one continuous path of approach to origin where the limit does not match the value the function takes, the function is discontinuous. This is valid for continuity at any point not just origin. In this case I would try x=y.

Comment: @WindSoul $x = y$ or $y = mx$ is basically the same, and I tried that indeed, and the limit is zero. This is not a proof, though. It's just an idea to go on

Comment: No, I just made a mistake. Sry.

Comment: I believe that you don’t need to go past $\frac 12|y|$ because $(x,y)\to(0,0)\Leftrightarrow y\to 0$

Answer (score 1):

The last inequality proposed does not hold since
\begin{align*}
(|x| + |y|)^{2} = x^{2} + 2|xy| + y^{2} \geq x^{2} + y^{2} \geq 0 & \Rightarrow |x| + |y| \geq \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}
\end{align*}

In fact, it suffices to apply the squeeze theorem to the relation:
\begin{align*}
0\leq \left|\frac{x^{4}y^{3}}{x^{8} + y^{4}}\right| \leq \frac{|y|}{2} \leq |y|
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I was studying about the norm in $\ell^2$ and I missed a term. Can I write this:

$$|x| + |y| \leq C\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

For some constant $C$ we don't care about. In this way the inequality can be satisfied

Comment: @Numb3rs $C=\sqrt2 $.